# SSL Unsupported Protocol on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, raspbian, tls1.2

When I try to connect to a MySQL Database from my Raspberry Pi, I get this error:

```
system error: 1 [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Other Platforms work fine. Is there any fix? Please tell me if you need more info. Any help is appreciated. Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found the solution. By doing `sudo nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and scrolling to the end, I could change the MIN_VERSION value to be version 1.0 instead of 1.2. This fixed it. This is just for the future in case other people have the same problem!